# AuditQuery Hibernate add order by partition

Tags: hibernate, audit, database-partitioning

I have `AuditQuery` and I want to add `order by` with `partition by`.

like I have  :

```
final AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(em);
final List<Test> result = new ArrayList<Test>();

final AuditQuery query =
    reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Test.class, false, true);
```

and I would like to do something like :

```
ORDER by (MAX(VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID))
```

how to do it in `AuditQuery` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AuditQuery`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/envers/query/AuditQuery.html) is built on top of Hibernate Criteria, so it doesn't support window functions, in which case you need to write a native SQL.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Can you show how to do this on audit table?